# Two inputs next to each other with box-shadow

Tags: css, shadow, overlapping

I'm trying to add a box shadow on two inputs next to each other, but the shadows are overlapping the inputs.

I've tried to add a `position: relative` and `z-index` to the inputs, but then the shadow overlap the input with the lowest z-index.

Is there a way to prevent the shadow from overlapping the other input next to it?

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="email" type="text" >
  <input name="send" type="submit">
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.email {
  height:45px;
  width: 395px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.search {
  height: 45px;
  width: 60px;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Here is an example of what i mean:
[image]

Thanks :)
- Jesper

Comment: provide your css and html code

Comment: Your HTML and CSS would be incredibly helpful

Comment: wrap them in a container and add the shadow to that?

Comment: margin equivalent to shadow spread i.e. 40px in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the two inputs into divs :

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="input--email">
         <input name="email" type="text" class="email">
    </div>
    <div class="input--search">
         <input name="send" type="submit" class="search">
    </div>
</form>
```

And give them the same shadows :

```
.input--email, .input--search {
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 45px;
}
.input--email{
    width: 395px;
}
.input--search{
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 60px;
}
.email, .search {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.search {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/VLy6Q/